# Any built-in function for picking up random values from a column

Tags: java, excel

In an Excel sheet, I want to read the values from a column, pick a random value from it and display in another column. Is there any way to do that in java?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Is that all?

Comment: @Naksha , add some piece of code, no one will give whole code,

Comment: @Sandip ND Well I don't want any code. I just want to know if there is any built-in function for picking up random values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache POI can be used to read and write to the Excel File. For more information refer the link: [Apache POI - Read and Write Excel File](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/).

For picking a random value from the column and writing it - you can use java.util.Random library and generate random numbers and use it to fetch the value from source and replace it in destination.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go through the link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get column list size. Then use 
`Math.random`
 to generate random value.
Better to use random in range (for example if your first column has index different from 0)

```
int a = 0; // from (first index)
int b = 10; // to (list.size()-1)

int randomNumber = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // generates random value from 0 to 10
```

After that, using Apache POI go to needed column and select cell with randomNumber index.